# Intel Evo Laptop - Display Flickering Issue

Tags: laptop, graphics-card

I hope you are all doing well. I'm reaching out to this wonderful community to seek some guidance regarding an issue I'm facing with my [Intel Evo laptop](https://www.lenovo.com/us/en/d/deals/intel-evo-for-home/).

I recently purchased an Intel Evo certified laptop, and overall, I've been quite pleased with its performance and features. However, over the past few days, I've noticed a peculiar problem with the display. It occasionally starts flickering for a few seconds, which can be quite distracting and annoying. I haven't made any significant software or hardware changes recently, so I'm a bit perplexed as to what might be causing this issue.

Here are some additional details about my laptop:

```
Model: Intel Evo certified laptop (12th Generation Intel® Core™ i5-1240P Processor (E-cores up to 3.30 GHz P-cores up to 4.40 GHz))
Processor: Intel Core i5 12th Gen
Graphics: Integrated Intel® Iris® Xe Graphics
Operating System: Windows 10
```

I've tried a few troubleshooting steps to address the problem, such as updating the display drivers, running a system scan for malware, and adjusting the display settings, but unfortunately, none of these actions have resolved the issue. The flickering occurs intermittently and seems to be independent of the applications I'm running or the power source.

I'm wondering if any other Intel Evo laptop owners have experienced a similar problem or have any suggestions for a potential solution.

Comment: If it's still under warranty then return it.

Comment: Try to find some information in the Event Viewer, but if there is nothing, then use your warranty.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the [refresh rate](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-your-display-refresh-rate-in-windows-c8ea729e-0678-015c-c415-f806f04aae5a) (frequency)? If the AC mains were ~50 Hz, causing LED and fluorescent light to flicker at that rate, and the refresh rate is 60 Hz, there is a noticeable 10 Hz flicker, as the ambient light and monitor go in and out of phase.

Choose a [frequency that is the same](https://www.hellotech.com/guide/for/how-to-change-monitor-refresh-rate-windows-10) as that of the AC mains, or an exact multiple. A 1 Hz flicker is *very* distracting. BTW, stay within specs of the display and graphics. If you *do* pick the wrong rate, though, Windows will automatically revert to the previous setting in 15 seconds if you *do not* confirm the change.